# Working with Javascript BBCode Editor

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I know question seems different as there are many BBCodes available out there, I am working on client Side BBCode editor and pretty much had done the work.

The issue i am facing is: when i try to parse the server side data with this:

```
<cfset show = "<script type='text/javascript'>var data = '#JSStringFormat(answer)#';
                    document.write(PARSER(data));</script>">
```

in my view source, it shows like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>var data = '[b]Thanks, This ticket has been Updated[/b]. ';
                    document.write(PARSER(data));</script>
```

How can i handle this issue?. I need some good suggestions here

Comment: What's the issue? What is the CF variable `answer` supposed to return?

Comment: The Issue is inn View Source, it is showing raw javascript as i defined above. I ned that it should parse it and show as normal text, rather than showing as javascript modified code.

Comment: When in doubt, look at your data.  In this case, I would output it into a textarea so that the browser doesn't hide anything.  Start with answer.  Then look at data.  Then look at show.

Comment: i did not understood what you mean @Dan

Answer (score 0):

use htmlEditFormat in conjunction with your JSStringFormat function.
`var data = '#JSStringFormat(htmlEditFormat(answer))#';`
JSStringFormat used alone is prone to XSS attacks.
See Nadal's post 
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2570-For-Better-Security-Use-HtmlEditFormat-In-Conjunction-With-JSStringFormat-In-ColdFusion.htm